# How to save model when using TFRobertaForSequenceClassification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I use keras.model.save() when the model is TFRobertaForSequenceClassification

But when i load the saved model,there are bugs.And i surf the internet but do not get the right answer
This is my code below:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (dict(train_encoding),y_train)
)
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (dict(val_encoding),y_val)
)

model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL,num_labels=1)

optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=1e-5, weight_decay=1e-6)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss = "mean_squared_error",metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(8),epochs=10,batch_size=8)
y_pred = model.predict(val_dataset.batch(8))
y_predicted = [y[0] for y in y_pred.logits.tolist()]
score = metrics_pearson(y_predicted,y_val)
model.save("./model1")

model1 = load_model("./model1")
print(model1.predict(val_dataset.batch(8)))
```

And then it raised up some Error.Is it because I defined a custom layer?

I looked up the information, but basically it said that the data type of the parameter I passed in was wrong, but I checked the data type in my val_dataset, they are all tf.int32 and tf.float32:

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (11 total):
    * {'input_ids': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids_1:0' shape=(None, 512) dtype=int32>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids:0' shape=(None, 512) dtype=int32>}
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (11 total):
    * {'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')}
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (11 total):
    * {'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')}
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: but when i use save_weights, it works. It confuses me a lot